# How can I use `find` to quickly search for, and return the location of, a specific directory on macOS without knowing where it might be?

Tags: bash, macos, shell, zsh

I'm creating a CLI for my team to automate some repetitive tasks that we have to do. In order to avoid them having to configure the CLI with where their project is located, I'd like to search for the name of the project upon first run.

I know that I need to use `find`, but I'm having problems figuring out how to properly use it. I've looked at many SO and SU answers, but nothing has really helped me so far.

One problem is that I'm unsure of the directory syntax when specifying `-name`. I've seen it done in several different ways: `'DirName'`, `'/DirName'`, `'/DirName/'`, and `'*/DirName/'`. I figure the last one is probably right, because of the wildcard and the slashes, but I just don't know.

Another problem is that I need the search to run quickly. The basic `find / "DirName" -type d` isn't enough because looks at all directories, so it's pretty slow. So I looked at trying to exclude certain directories like `/System` and `/Library`, but there's a *lot* more stuff to exclude. I've looked at using `-mindepth 1` but that hasn't really helped me either.

Lastly, I need *only* the path of the project to be returned from the command, and nothing else.

There must be some way to do this that isn't verbose and runs in about 30 seconds or less.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: If the script that's searching is in the directory you want to find, can't it just use a path relative to its own location?

Comment: You might have a look at `mdfind` since you are on MacOS. It is instant.

Comment: The traditional `find` tool is innately slow, because it does an actual traversal of the filesystem tree. If "quickly" is part of your specification, it's the wrong tool (so why are you making it part of your question in the title?)

Comment: And no, `-name '*/DirName/'` is not correct -- `-name` only checks the current component's name, the _last_ part of the path; `/`s don't make sense in it. The equivalent that checks full paths is `-path`, but using that won't fix your efficiency problems.

Comment: I wasn't aware of `mdfind`, which is why I specify the usage of `find`. I'll take a look at `mdfind` and report my findings. Thanks!

Comment: dont understand having the tag bash and zsh , which are you interested in? or do you not care which as long it works on terminal?

Comment: OK so `mdfind "ProjName" kind:folder` works, but it also returns subdirectories of "ProjName". Is there a way to exclude those subdirectories?

Comment: "why I specify the use of find" -- but if you don't know the options, why specify _anything at all_? Better to let the people you're asking for help from suggest the appropriate tool for the job, instead of asking people to limit themselves to something that may not be the best choice.

Comment: Personally, I'd just sort the results -- subdirectories should always come after the parent so they're easy to exclude.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy true that my desired result is the first one, but this output will get piped back to my CLI, and I'd rather not have to parse out that line. Is there a way to limit the search results to one?

Comment: Well, the _obvious_ thing is `mdfind ... | head -n 1`

Comment: You can use `-onlyin dir` to limit the scope.

Comment: `mdfind "ProjName" kind:folder | head -n 1` worked, thank you! I'll post it as the answer.

Comment: I disagree that it's a suitable answer to a Stack Overflow question. Maybe it would be an answer to a [unix.se] question or an [apple.se] question, but SO is only for software development questions, not end-user UNIX utility usage questions; if you're writing a script, you should care much more about correctness and much less about terseness, since you don't control the environment your script is going to be called in, and things you don't control or expect are much more likely.

Comment: `-name` gets as argument a [glog-pattern](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man7/glob.7.html) which is matched against the respective directory entry.  Whether this entry refers to a file or to a directory, is regulated separately by the `-type` parameter. Hence `-name "x*" -type d` would match all directories starting with the letter `x`.

Comment: _Another problem is that I..._ : Please ask only one thing in one question. If you have several problems, ask several questions. If you ask many questions at once, how could you select the best answer afterwards?

Answer (score 1):

Credit to @charles-duffy - the solution was to instead use `mdfind`, which I wasn't aware of previously:

```bash
mdfind "ProjName" kind:folder | head -n 1
```

where `head -n 1` specifies to only return the first result, which is the exact match (the rest of the results will be subdirectories of the searched folder).

Answer (score 0):

If you were asking how to do this *as a user* it would be off-topic here and better suited to [UNIX & Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com/) or [Ask Different](https://apple.stackexchange.com/). Consequently, I'm assuming that you're asking how to do it *as a developer* where you have code interpreting the output and it makes more sense to have that code be robust and readable rather than terse and occasionally wrong.

```
mdfind -name "$name" kind:folder | LC_ALL=C sort | {
        read -r line && {
                last=$line
                echo "$line" # first line from sorted sequence is always a result
                while IFS= read -r line; do
                        [[ $line = $last/* ]] && continue
                        last=$line
                        echo "$line" # we found an additional top-level result
                done
        }
}
```

Note that we support finding multiple matches -- as there may genuinely be multiple directories with the same name on your system -- but exclude matches that are underneath any other matches.